# Sql compare record to other records from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

this is probably simple for you (but I'm a beginner).

I have a table named `Table_1` with the following columns:

```
[id]
[command]
[verify_date]
[data_interval_start]
[data_interval_end]
```

Data inside the table looks like this:

```
id  command     verify_date  data_interval_start   data_interval_end
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   123456      2013-02-01   2013-05-01            2013-05-06 
2   234513      2012-05-02   2013-01-01            2013-03-01 
3   221342      2013-05-04   2011-01-01            2011-01-02
```

I want to check if the `verify_date` is between each of the `data_interval_start` and `data_interval_end`;
So take the first `verify_date` value and check it between all records between `data_interval_start` and `data_interval_end`.

I've tried this queries but with no result:

```
SELECT command from Table_1 
WHERE verify_date IN (data_interval_start, data_interval_end)


SELECT command from Table_1 
WHERE verify_date between data_interval_start AND data_interval_end 


SELECT command from Table_1 
WHERE verify_date = data_interval_start OR verify_date = data_interval_end
```

Any help is appreciated :).

Thanks

Comment: So is the objective to find if a particular verify_date is between ALL the pairs of (data_interval_start,data_interval_end)

Comment: 'BETWEEN' (2nd example) should work for you. In your sample data you dont have any record which satisfy the condition!

Comment: Jit B.....yes.....example:

<br>
Verify if 2013-02-01 is between all, the pairs of (data_interval_start,data_interval_end)<br>
Next, verify if 2012-05-02 is between all, the pairs of (data_interval_start,data_interval_end) and so on....

Comment: Prasanna, it's returning 0 rows.....like Jit B. said:  the objective is to find if a particular verify_date is between ALL the pairs of (data_interval_start,data_interval_end)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are `DATE type fields`, you could use a `CASE` as below;

```
select id, command, case when verify_date between  
                              data_interval_start and  data_interval_end 
                         then 'Yes'
                         else 'No' 
                    end isBetween
from table1
```

If your dates are string type fields then get them into `ISO format` (`yyyymmdd`) and convert to DATE for comparison like below;

```
select id, command, case when convert(date,replace(verify_date,'-','')) between  
                              convert(date,replace(data_interval_start,'-','')) 
                              and convert(date,replace(data_interval_end,'-',''))  
                         then 'Yes'
                         else 'No' 
                    end isBetween
from table1
```

**EDIT:** If you need to compare a given date, you could do it as below. (Please note that between is inclusive. So if you need to exclude `data_interval_start` and `data_interval_end`, then use `<` and `>` operators)

```
--say this is the date you need to compare your records with
declare @verify_date date = '20130201'

select id, command
from table1
where @verify_date between convert(date, data_interval_start) 
                              and convert(date, data_interval_end)
```

To do for all the `varify_date`, you could use a `cross join` like below.

**[Sql-Fiddle-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fe82/5)**

```
select t1.id, t1.command, t2.verify_date
from table1 t1 cross join table1 t2
where t2.verify_date between convert(date, t1.data_interval_start) 
                              and convert(date, t1.data_interval_end)

| ID | COMMAND | VERIFY_DATE |
------------------------------
|  2 |  234513 |  2013-02-01 |
|  1 |  123456 |  2013-05-04 |
```

Comment: Kaf, but it's wrong, verify_date 2013-02-01 is between the second pair of records: 2013-01-01            2013-03-01

Comment: Are you looking for `verify_date` between in any start and end dates regardless of their data record relation?

Comment: the objective is to find if a particular verify_date is between ALL the pairs of (data_interval_start,data_interval_end)

Comment: What are the data types of those date fields? And are you looking to filter those dates or just to say `yes/no` in a new field?

Comment: The data type is : datetime

Comment: Looking to show if a certain command is between data_interval_start and data_interval_end based on the verify_date (but i want to verification to check if the verify_date is between all of the other 2 fields start-end)

Comment: Kaf, your last solution worked....but how can i do it without declaring: declare @verify_date date = '20130201, i want to take each verify_date and compare them to the fields and get the same results.

Comment: Your requirement is bit unusual, but I think updated answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are comparing two strings try to convert them to `DATE`

like that

```
     select command from Table_1 where convert(CHAR(10),verify_date,111) 
     between convert(CHAR(10),data_interval_start,111)  AND convert(CHAR(10),data_interval_end,111)
```

[here how to convert dates](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: select command from Table_1 where convert(CHAR(10),verify_date,111) 
     between convert(CHAR(10),data_interval_start,111)  AND convert(CHAR(10),data_interval_end,111) **returned 0 rows**

Comment: Found another solution:

**select t1.id, t1.command, t2.verify_date
from table_1 t1, Table_1 t2
where t2.verify_date between t1.data_interval_start and t1.data_interval_end**

Answer (score 0):

your second query will work for you

```
SELECT command from Table_1 
WHERE verify_date between data_interval_start AND data_interval_end 

id  command     verify_date  data_interval_start   data_interval_end
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   123456      2013-02-01   2013-05-01            2013-05-06 
2   234513      2012-05-02   2012-01-01            2013-03-01 
3   221342      2013-05-04   2011-01-01            2011-01-02
```

now check with above data